# Way to show texerror in MathJax

Tags: mathjax

I'm using cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full

When MathJax tries to render `$$2^2^x$$`, it shows 2^2^x instead of error "Double exponent: use braces to clarify"

What configuration should I use in order to show the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  TeX: {
    noErrors: {disabled: true}
  }
});
</script>
```

just *before* the script that loads `MathJax.js` itself.  That will display the error messages instead of the original TeX code.